# Multiple Conditions for Array Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, conditional-statements

I'm looking to use an array formula to makes lists of students who have entered different events, but also need to split by gender.

I have the first array working where it lists the students in each event but can't seem to get the second condition to work properly.

[image: img]

Here is my working formula for the first event lists:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$502,SMALL(IF($C$3:$C$502=1,ROW($C$3:$C$502)-ROW($C$3)+1),ROWS($C$3:$C3))),"")`

Here is my non-working attempt at the second one:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$502,SMALL(IF(AND($C$3:$C$15=1,$B$3:$B$15="F"),ROW($C$3:$C$15)-ROW($C$3)+1),ROWS($C$3:$C3))),"")`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A, aggregate(15, 6, row($3:$502)/(($C$3:$C$502=1)*($B$3:$B$502="F")), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

I have no idea why your sample formula had the criteria ranges going down to row 15; the ranges need to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Array formula do not like `AND` or `OR` use `*` and `+` respectively.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($C$3:$C$15=1)*($B$3:$B$15="F")),ROW($C$3:$C$15)),ROW($A1))),"")
```